# Create custom module in drupal 6.x

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I want to create a custom module for my drubal site and I followed this how to: http://drupal.org/node/206760

However the module does not show up in my module list. I use drubal 6.x.

I placed the module file in sites/all/modules/mymodule with

**mymodule.info**

```
name = My Module
description = another module
core = 6.x
```

However it does not show up in module list. Why? Permissions are set correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the other mymodule.module file and to clear the cache.

Once you've done that it should show up in your modules page.